# Взаимодействие между модулями Android

Tags: android, 1с, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Я программирую на 1С, который очень ограничен в аппаратном взаимодействии. Есть небольшие знания Java, чтобы хоть немного въехать. Встала задача в следующем:
Необходимо создать внешнюю компоненту для взаимодействия с электронными весами, которые работают на Android. В частности: необходимо получить вес. После длительного поиска информации я не понял с чего начать и как можно обратиться к модулю(?) весов.
Т.е. в стандартной библиотеке Android есть класс Camera, есть класс взаимодействия с GPS, но как понять какой класс отвечает за взаимодействие с весами? Или можно ли как-то его узнать? Дайте наводку, куда гуглить и что искать дальше

P.S. Да, лучше бы отдать такую задачу мобильному разработчику, но имею, что имею

Comment: Начать надо с документации электронных весов; В которой и будет описан способ взаимодействия со сторонними программами (если такой имеется); Далее проверяем способна ли 1С получать данные указанным способом

Comment: Что же это за весы такие.. можешь ссылку дать? Я слышал только про весы с блютуз, к которым можно конектится с андроида.

Comment: Весы M-ER 725

@santavital есть документация, но там только информация по протоколу обмена. А вот куда посылать эти данные - я так и не понял. Я думал, что это должно быть примерно как с той же камерой, но что-то не сходится. Можно написать производителю, но хотелось бы хотя бы знать, что спросить... примерно)

Comment: Давай ещё раз более подробно: 1. Твоя программа получающая данные с весов работает на: а) Андроид б) Windows ?   2. Выложи документацию ! На сайте - не дают скачать.

Comment: https://mertech.ru/blog/vse-o-vesah/kak-podkljuchit-vesy-m-er-k-«1spredprijatie»-na-primere-m-er-222f/

Comment: @santavital
1. Работает на Android. Т.е. будет мобильная платформа 1С, которая должна получить вес через внешнюю компоненту. Внешняя компонента же будет обращаться к Android (по идее)
2. Документация: https://mertech.gitlab.io/docs. В любом из разделов есть пункт «Интеграция» и там есть информация по протоколу обмена. Есть информация по драйверам, но опять же: это для связи от ПК к штатной программе на весах. Мне же нужно обратиться, получается, к Android'у. Если я правильно понимаю

Comment: Андроид тебе ни чего не подскажет, надо через программу взаимодействовать, ее api. Похоже что это надо делать как раз на стороне ПК, связавшись с программой, как в их доке описано.

Answer (score 0):

@Treaq Сами весы, насколько я понял, подключаются к пк по COM порту ? Если так, то каким образом ты собираешься их подключить к Андроид-девайсу считывающему данные ?

В примере на Kotlin есть намёк что подключиться к ним можно по IP адресу, в этом случае вероятно надо будет написать Андроид-приложение получающее/отправляющее данные с весов. А на следующем этапе организовать взаимодействие между 1С-на-андроиде и нашим Андроид-приложением-на-Kotlin

```
fun main(){
    val driver = MertechPrintScalesDriver()
    //Подключение
    driver.setStringParam(ParamType.Ip, "192.168.1.111")
    driver.setStringParam(ParamType.Port, "1111")
    driver.setStringParam(ParamType.AdminPassword, "1234")
    driver.setIntParam(ParamType.ConnectTimeout, 4)
    driver.executeCommand(CommandType.CONNECT)

    //Получение названия магазина
    driver.setIntParam(ParamType.StringNumber, 1)
    val res1 = driver.executeCommand(CommandType.GET_NAME_SHOP)
    if(res1 == 0){
        val shopName = driver.getStringParam(ParamType.ShopName)
    }

    //Запись нового названия магазина
    driver.setIntParam(ParamType.StringNumber, 1)
    driver.setStringParam(ParamType.ShopName, "Пример названия")
    driver.executeCommand(CommandType.GET_NAME_SHOP)
}
```

Comment: Я хочу установить мобильное приложение 1С на весы и в этом приложении получить вес. С ПК я видел примеры и есть штатное приложение на этих весах и оно, вроде как, это и делает. Но у меня то своё мобильное приложение будет. И как в нём получение того же веса реализовать - не понимаю. Написал ещё в ТП производителя, может чего-нибудь подскажут